# Initializing String from JOptionPane inside of an ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, joptionpane

I am trying to use a `JOptionPane` to create a popup window for the user to give some input.  I then need to use that input elsewhere.  I am getting the error `The final local variable answer cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type` for `answer` in `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` (See below).  Is there a way to have the user input a `String` in the popup window while allowing the main window the have access to that `String`?

```
final String answer;
JButton getAnswerButton = getAnswerButton();
getAnswerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the answer?");
    }
});
System.out.println(answer);  //Need access to answer *outside* of my JButton
```

Comment: Call another method from your `actionPerformed()` method, with the string input form the end user, it should work.

Comment: @Laf Are you suggesting to make answer a global variable?  I'd rather steer clear of that if possible.  (But it does appear to work, thanks for the option!)

Comment: @Evorlor Java does not have global variables. Having a variable at the class level is normal practice (as long as the variable "belongs" to the class)

Comment: @Nivas thanks. terminology is not my strong point :)

Comment: @Evorlor it is more of meaning. Java does not have pure global variable like `c++`, so problems generally associated with global variables are not present in Java. Now, if the entire code of an application is in one class, class level variables become same as global variables, causing the same problems. But here the issue is having a [God object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is declated `final` in Java, a value can be assigned once to the variable but cannot be changed.

To change the value, you may need to remove `final` from the declation.  In your case, you will get another error that a non-final local variable cannot be used in (anonymous) inner classes (which is probably why you added the `final` in the first place).

Depending on what your application is doing, making `answer` a class level variable (rather than a method level one) is one solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make `answer` a field member in your class. You simply cannot refer to a local variable defined in a method from an inner class unless it is `final`, and since it should be `final` you cannot assign it again in the inner class. The requirement of making it `final` is due to the fact that changes done by the inner class `ActionListener` to variables declared in the method calling the inner class will not be visible to that method.

A better way would be something like:

```
public class YourClass {
   String answer;

   ...

   public void setButtonListener() {
      JButton getAnswerButton = getAnswerButton();
      getAnswerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the answer?");
        }
      });
   }

   public void displayAnswer() {
      System.out.println(answer);  //Need access to answer *outside* of my JButton
   }
}
```

You would call `setButtonListener` during the setup which would add a listener to the button to set the field, and then you would be able to access the field after the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The prefered option would be to call a protected or private method with the answer as a parameter. This is more convenient since there is no member field involved in and it keeps things together.

```
public class YourClass {

   public void setButtonListener() {
      JButton getAnswerButton = getAnswerButton();
      getAnswerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the answer?");
           displayAnswer(answer);
        }
      });
   }

   protected void displayAnswer(String answer) {
      System.out.println(answer);  //Need access to answer *outside* of my JButton
   }
}
```

Comment: That would certainly be my preferred solution ;)